# Prometheus- total time of function

Tags: python, django, prometheus, grafana

I am using Prometheus and Grafana on my Django project.
I decorated with Prometheus a few functions that eventually did API calls.

```
PROMETHEUS_TIME = Histogram(
name="method_latency_seconds",
documentation='total time',
labelnames=('component', 'container', 'tenant', 'app', 'metric_name'))
```

I want to get the maximum; I tried to do a graph on Grafana but had no success:

```
method_latency_seconds{app='my_app', metric='my_metric'}
```

this promQL show me NO DATA while method_latency_seconds_**sum**{app='my_app', metric='my_metric'} or method_latency_seconds_**count**{app='my_app', metric='my_metric'}
showing data but not what I'm searching for.

Is someone can help me to get the maximum? Is there another way to get data that is not Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

use the `histogram_quantile` function in Prometheus. It gets the maximum latency value for a specific combination of labels.

For example:

```
histogram_quantile(0.999, sum(rate(method_latency_seconds_bucket{app='my_app', metric_name='my_metric'}[5m])) by (le))
```